# Make a custom Java annotation required

Tags: java, annotations

Say I am hypothetically writing a string builder for queries:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SearchQuery {
}
```

and:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Search {
}
```

So `@Search` class has `@SearchQuery` methods that return strings:

```
@Search
public class Queries extends Query{

    @SearchQuery
    public String queryEverything(){
        return "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
    }

}
```

Main question:

A. Is it possible for me to make a class of annotation `@Search` enforce that at least one method of `@SearchQuery` exists?

Other questions:

B. Is it possible to enforce that a method of `@SearchQuery` always returns a string?

C. I have RetentionPolicy set to Runtime as I want to do some reflections, but only in testing: My annotations would be `SOURCE` otherwise. Is it ok to keep it as `RUNTIME` despite having no purpose in production?

I'll take any sort of improvement over my current setup, please share anything other than moving away from sql strings, it is just for example purposes.

Comment: Seems like you want to [write a annotation processor](http://tutortutor.ca/cgi-bin/makepage.cgi?/articles/byoap). So the answers to the first 2 questions are: Yes and yes.